# How to convert input parameter type in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, function, type-conversion

Can I declare a function in postgresql which in its input parameter will convert data type of passed parameter.
For example:

```
create or replace function temp(IN var1 integer, IN var2 varchar)
<function body>

select temp('12345','number');
```

as passed parameter `'12345'` is a string, I want it to convert directly into integer while passing it to function, something like this:

```
create or replace function temp(IN var1 ::integer, IN var2 varchar)
    <function body>
```

Is it possible?

Note: I cannot convert value while passing it to the function like this:

```
select temp('12345'::integer,'number');
```

I have to convert it in function definition itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a cast from `text` to `integer`, but that's a bad idea as it will lead to surprising behavior somewhere else.

You have two choices:

- Cast the argument to `integer` before passing it to the function.
- Cast the argument to `integer` inside the function.

Comment: So, this means I can not perform conversion in function definition itself and I have do it explicitly inside the function?

Comment: Right. Type conversion while passing the argument would be an assignment or implicit cast, and I recommend that you do not go that way.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalRecords (P1 int, P2 int)
> RETURNS integer AS $total$
> declare
>   total integer;
> BEGIN
>    total := P1 * P2;
>    RETURN total;
> END;
> $total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select totalRecords('12', 3)
> ```
>
> ```
> | totalrecords |
> | -----------: |
> |           36 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a4769be8bdaa9fcb77d1d4a226867884)*

You could use **[CREATE CAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createcast.html)** if you need special data type.

> CREATE CAST defines a new cast. A cast specifies how to perform a conversion between two data types.

```
CREATE CAST (source_type AS target_type)
    WITH FUNCTION function_name (argument_type [, ...])
    [ AS ASSIGNMENT | AS IMPLICIT ]

CREATE CAST (source_type AS target_type)
    WITHOUT FUNCTION
    [ AS ASSIGNMENT | AS IMPLICIT ]

CREATE CAST (source_type AS target_type)
    WITH INOUT
    [ AS ASSIGNMENT | AS IMPLICIT ]
```

Comment: I cannot convert it while calling the function, see Note in question.